# Prove that if $S=\left\{\frac{1}{n}\,:\,n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$, then $S \cap S' =\varnothing$ where $S'$ is the set of accumulation points of $S$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the set $S=\left\{\frac{1}{n}\,:\,n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$. I would like to prove that its set of accumulation points $S'$ satisfies $S \cap S' = \varnothing$. Specifically, I want to demonstrate that if $x \in S$, then $x \not \in S'$ without knowing what $S'$ is. Any hints? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I'll rewrite the post.

Answer (score 1):

A point $x$ is in $S'$ if any only if for any open interval $I$ centered at $x,$ there is at least one $y\in I$ such that $y\ne x.$ Consequently, to prove that no point of $S$ can be an element of $S',$ we need only show that for any $x\in S$, there is an open interval $I_0$ centered at $x$ such that $x$ is the only element of $I_0$ that is also an element of $S.$

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to show pretty easily that $1/n\rightarrow 0$, and thus 0 is an accumulation point of $S$.  Now you just need to show that no point in $S$ is an accumulation point of $S$.  $1/n$ is a decreasing sequence, so for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $1/(n-1)>1/n>1/(n+1)$, and there does not exist $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m\not=n$ and $1/(n-1)>1/m>1/(n+1)$.  Thus, letting $\varepsilon<1/n-1/(n+1)$ gives you that no point of $S$ that is not $1/n$ is in $B_{\varepsilon}(1/n)$ and thus $1/n$ isn't an accumulation point of $S$.